# Rearranging an equation with vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation with vectors (latin letters) and a scalar (greek letter):

$$\alpha m_1 = x - m_2$$

I am triing to express alpha. Do I multiply by $ m_1^{-1} $ from the left or from the right to achieve this? I will also need to do a transposition to get a scalar. How do I decide what to transpose?

Comment: If $x$ is the unknown, then $x=\alpha m_1+m_2$. WHat does ${m_1}^{-1}$ mean?

Comment: Since alpha is a scalar, it will be impossible (and nonsensical) to try to express it as a combination of vectors.

Comment: If $m_1$, $m_2$ and $x$ are vectors, this does not always have a solution. There's a solution if vectors $m_1$ and $x-m_2$ are parallel, in other words $m_1 \times (x-m_2) = 0$. If this is true, then you can get $\alpha$ just by comparing the values ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\alpha m_1 = x - m_2$$

if $m_1=0$, this case is easy.

Otherwise.

$$\alpha m_1^Tm_1 = m_1^T(x-m_2)$$

$$\alpha \|m_1\|^2=m_1^T(x-m_2)$$

Hopefully solving for $\alpha$ is doable now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sadly, I am selft-educated in math and linear algebra, could you maybe point me to a resource where I can study the rules for doing algebra with equations containing vector and matrix terms?

Comment: unfortunately, I am not able to recommend any textbook as I don't use one. I heard Gilbert Strang textbook and linear algebra done right  are good books.